# How to solve vba runtime error 3420

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following the detect duplicate product name when user enters a new record.

```
Private Sub ProdName_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Dim Product As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim rsc As DAO.Recordset

Set rsc = Me.RecordsetClone

Product = Me.ProdName.value
stLinkCriteria = "[ProdName]=" & "'" & Product & "'"

    If DCount("ProdName", "ProdProduct", stLinkCriteria) > 0 Then
        Me.Undo
        MsgBox "Warning duplicate entry " _
        & Product & " has already been entered." _
        & vbCr & vbCr & "You will now be taken to the record.", vbInformation _
        , "Duplicate Information"
        'Go to record of original product name 
        rsc.FindFirst stLinkCriteria
        Me.Bookmark = rsc.Bookmark
    End If

Set rsc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code checks and finds duplicate but after it displays the following error and doesn't go to the orginal record:

Run-time error '3420'
Object invalid or no longer set

Please can someone help me get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the undo (or move it to the end) and do cancel the update:

```
If DCount("ProdName", "ProdProduct", stLinkCriteria) > 0 Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Warning duplicate entry " _
    & Product & " has already been entered." _
    & vbCr & vbCr & "You will now be taken to the record.", vbInformation _
    , "Duplicate Information"
    'Go to record of original product name 
    rsc.FindFirst stLinkCriteria
    Me.Bookmark = rsc.Bookmark
End If
```

And you may even skip the *DCount* and must use the *Text* property:

```
Product = Me!ProdName.Text
stLinkCriteria = "[ProdName]=" & "'" & Product & "'"

rsc.FindFirst stLinkCriteria
Cancel = Not rsc.NoMatch 

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Warning duplicate entry " _
    & Product & " has already been entered." _
    & vbCr & vbCr & "You will now be taken to the record.", vbInformation _
    , "Duplicate Information"
    'Go to record of original product name 
    Me.Bookmark = rsc.Bookmark
End If
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't do the magic. Tried both and still getting error.

Comment: Then probably `Product = Me!ProdName.Value` has no value. Try `Text` - see edit.

Comment: Nope doesn't work. Maybe I should try apply the same logic in another way. All I am looking for is to prevent duplicate when entering data at form level.

Comment: Yes, use the BeforeUpdate event of the _form_.

Answer (score 0):

The Run-time Error 3420, Object Invalid or No Longer Set occurs when the form status is dirty, you can simply set the form dirty to false before .findFirst call.

```
   If Me.Dirty Then
      Me.Dirty = False
   End If

   Me.Recordset.FindFirst stLinkCriteria
```